# Having a syntax issue with MySQL Query with Multiple AND operators

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry newbie here but I'm having trouble getting this query to work and if there is a simpler way to do this I would appreciate the feedback, thanks.

```
SELECT players.FirstName, players.LastName, stats.PtsPerGame, 
stats.AstPerGame, stats.RebPerGame, stats.StlPerGame, stats.BlkPerGame 
WHERE stats.PtsPerGame >= 20 
AND stats.AstPerGame >= 3 
AND stats.RebPerGame >= 3 
AND stats.StlPerGame >= 2 
AND stats.BlkPerGame >= 1
From players 
INNER JOIN stats 
ON players.PlayerID = stats.PID 
ORDER BY stats.PtsPerGame DESC;
```

I get this error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE stats.PtsPerGame >= 20

AND stats.AstPerGame >= 3
AND stats.RebPerGame ' at line 2

Comment: you are missing `FROM`

Comment: The correct order of your several parts is `select ... from ... join .... where ... order by`. Not  `select ... where ... from ... join ... order by`

Comment: works like a charm, thanks

Comment: Syntax is incredibly simple in SQL. And incredibly consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Where condition always appears after `from tablename`

```
SELECT players.FirstName, players.LastName, stats.PtsPerGame, stats.AstPerGame, stats.RebPerGame, stats.StlPerGame, stats.BlkPerGame From players INNER JOIN stats ON players.PlayerID = stats.PID WHERE stats.PtsPerGame >= 20 AND stats.AstPerGame >= 3 AND stats.RebPerGame >= 3 AND stats.StlPerGame >= 2 AND stats.BlkPerGame >= 1 ORDER BY stats.PtsPerGame DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop your `WHERE` clause down to below your `FROM` and `JOIN`'s

Like this:

```
SELECT players.FirstName,
       players.LastName,
       stats.PtsPerGame,
       stats.AstPerGame,
       stats.RebPerGame,
       stats.StlPerGame,
       stats.BlkPerGame
FROM players
     INNER JOIN stats ON players.PlayerID = stats.PID
WHERE stats.PtsPerGame >= 20
      AND stats.AstPerGame >= 3
      AND stats.RebPerGame >= 3
      AND stats.StlPerGame >= 2
      AND stats.BlkPerGame >= 1
ORDER BY stats.PtsPerGame DESC;
```

Have a look [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) if you're new to all this :)